# The Conversion to type Double is not valid?

Tags: .net, vb.net, type-conversion, decimal, maskedinput

I have an error in VB.net 
`If CurrencyHolder.Text > 0 And CurrencyHolder.Text < 10000 Then`

I am using a Maskedinputbox 00000.00
When I perform my code and the Maskedinputbox is empty I get the following error:

**Tried my best to translate it!!!:$ )
The Conversion of signstreak      .  to type double is not valid

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [val()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9(v=vs.90).aspx) : - *Returns the numbers contained in a string as a numeric value of appropriate type*.

```
If Val(CurrencyHolder.Text) > 0 AndAlso Val(CurrencyHolder.Text) < 1000 Then
            'code
        End If
```

---

***caveats***

`val()` consider only `.` to check for a decimal separator incase the end user's lcoale style of decimal point is other than `.` this will not work

Comment: Hello Wingedpanther, this works! But I don't know why this works. Could you explain this to me:)?

Comment: @TheBlinderCoder Updated !!

Comment: but this will cause a runtime error if a user enter characters which cannot be cast

Comment: @5uperdan FYI, a maskedtextbox with `00000.00` mask will accepts only numerical values

Comment: Why `Val` and not .NET? Use `Double.Parse`/`Double.TryParse` or `Decimal.Parse`/`Decimal.TryParse`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  The Val function recognizes only the period (`.`) as a valid decimal separator(as per the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9(v=vs.90).aspx)), So when comes to OP's requirement his input is in the same format that is `00000.00` so `val()` comes in my mind OTOH  on different decimal separators we can use aforementioned methods

Comment: You can also use these methods if you want to support `.` as decimal separator. `Dim valid As Boolean = Decimal.TryParse(CurrencyHolder.Text, NumberStyles.Currency, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, currency)`. You could also pass a `CultureInfo` object instead of `NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` to support specific currencies.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Noted and  will check  later.

Comment: `Val` is not a good choice because you don't know whether the end user's locale will use `.` or another char as the decimal separator. If it uses another char then Val will fail. Specifying a `.` in for the maskedtextbox decimal separator does not guarantee this will always be displayed: "The actual display character used will be the decimal symbol appropriate to the format provider"

Answer (score 3):

Use `Double.Parse`/`Double.TryParse` or `Decimal.Parse`/`Decimal.TryParse`. For currencies `Decimal` is the proper type.

```
Dim currency as Decimal
Dim valid as Boolean = Decimal.TryParse(CurrencyHolder.Text, currency)

If valid AndAlso currency > 0 AndAlso currency < 10000 Then
    ' ... '
End If
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

If your current decimal separator is a different than the one you want to support(f.e. you use `123,50€` but the value you have to parse is `123.50$`) you can use the overload of the parse methods. For example:

```
Dim valid As Boolean = Decimal.TryParse(CurrencyHolder.Text, NumberStyles.Currency, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, currency)
```

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer and additionally you have correctly picked out that the Op should be using a decimal date type